# 6/2(1+2) returning error 2 is not a Function

Tags: c

The following statement is generating a compile-time error.

```
 int a=6/2(1+2);
```

Can someone please explain why the compiler generates an error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing a mathematical sign such as `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`.

You probably want `6/(2*(1+2))` or `(6/2)*(1+2)`.

If you leave the sign out, C interprets it as a function call just like usual functions `printf("stuff")` (indicated via opening parentheses without mathematical operator). So it thinks `2(1+2)` calls the function `2` with argument `1+2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't skip the multiplication operator. Try `int a=6/2*(1+2);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

```
int a = 6/2*(1+2);
```

Otherwise it tries to interpret 2 as a function, like `int a = 2(argument);`

Comment: @Rudy: You're making an assumption, while we're just answering the question about the error. If it ends up being the wrong number, I think the OP could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no operation between `2` and `(1 + 2)`. If you wanted to multiply, you have to let C know: the programming syntax is usually strict with this stuff.

The correct syntax:

```
int a = 6 / 2 * (1 + 2);
```